# Custom extensions for Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

There are short code snippets I often use during my Rails `script/console` sessions, like e.g.

```
>> app.get 'admin/login'
>> app.response.body
# look up 'authenticity_token' in the login form's HTML
>> login_data = { "authenticity_token" => "token_value",
                  "username" => "admin",
                  "password" => "admin_password" }
>> app.post 'admin/login', login_data
```

I'd like to make a helper method / extension for the console so I'd just use

```
>> app.admin_logon
```

What are the possible solutions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define helper functions in the file ~/.irbrc. This will affect all of your irb sessions, not just rails console sessions, so you may have to conditionally execute some helpers:

```
if defined? Rails
  [helper code here...]
end
```

Comment: Should be a per-repo solution that makes it available in the codebase to all users, not something specific to my user in which I manage 20 different projects conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a module in your project, in a folder that's loaded.
For example, add `console_extensions.rb` to your `lib` folder:

```rb
module ConsoleExtensions
  def admin_logon
    # custom code here
  end
end
```